# How to add custom field when verifying access token in rest_framework_simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I tried to override `validate` method at TokenVerifySerializer but this raises AttributeError.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenVerifySerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenVerifyView

class CustomTokenVerifySerializer(TokenVerifySerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super(CustomTokenVerifySerializer, self).validate(attrs)
        data.update({'fullname': self.user.fullname})
        return data


class CustomTokenVerifyView(TokenVerifyView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenVerifySerializer
```

But that does work when using TokenObtainPairSerializer and TokenObtainPairView.
The above snippet raises AttributeError with `'CustomTokenVerifySerializer' object has no attribute 'user'.`

Comment: Which version of django and python are using? Because you can call `super()` easier with `data = super().validate(attrs)`. By other hand, I was not able to find any error in you code, but for some reason the function `validate()` no contain the user. Why don't you try to print `data` to see its contain?

Answer (score 0):

The way adding custom fields in data is right I think. The problem is in `self.user.fullname`. Because the serializer doesn't have the `user` field. If you need user info in the serializer you have to get the user from DB.

But In this case, I think you need a current user or authenticated user. To get the authenticated user in the serializer you need to pass the `user` or `request` object as a context to the serializer. Here is an example:

```py
def validate(self, attrs):
    request = self.context.get('request', None)
    if request:
        user = request.user
```

And you have to initialize the serializer as below:

```
serializer = MySerializer(
    data=request.data,
    context={
        'request': request
    }
)
```